# Writing Binary Data to Named Pipes in Python

Tags: python-2.7, pipe, ctypes, named

Several months ago, I implemented a named pipe server in a GUI using the example code from MSDN -> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.

The named pipe server seems to work well, and I've used it to control my GUI with other programs written in various Visual Studio languages.

Today I have been trying to interact with the named pipe server with a Python script.  On the web, it was simple to find sample python code, using the ctypes library, that opened up the named pipe with the windll.kernel32.CreateFileA() method and wrote ASCII bytes to it with the windll.kernel32.WriteFile() method.

The problem is that the MSDN example uses a format where the first two bytes written to/received from the pipe represent the size of a string that is to follow in the pipe.  While I can write strings to the pipe from Python with no problem, I can't seem to pass any binary data into the WriteFile() method.

Questions about ways to solve this problem:
  1. Is there any way to write raw bytes of binary data to WriteFile()?  Is there another method I could be calling to handle this?
  2. Is there any way for me to encode the binary number into a string as raw bytes?  For example, if I knew the bytes I wanted to send ahead of time (0x1234 for example) then I could just send create_string_buffer("\x12\x34").  The bytes have to be determined at runtime, however, and I haven't found a way to create a string out of the raw bytes.

Comment: Why do you need ctypes to write to a named pipe? You should be able to open the address and write data: `f = open(r'\\.\pipe\some_pipe_1234', 'wb');` `f.write(data);` `f.flush()`. Use the struct module to pack the length into a big-endian short (2 bytes): `struct.pack('>H', length)`.

Comment: If there's another way to do it, I'll be happy to try it.  I was using sample code from the web (https://github.com/erochest/snippets/blob/master/win32named.py), however, and it seemed to be 90% of the way there with few modifications.  That sample code used ctypes, which seemed to make sense since it was interfacing to windows dlls.  I'll see what progress I can make with the method you're suggesting.

Comment: I actually ended up using a hack to make the code work.  I made a list to convert from integers to ascii (conversion_table = ["\x00", "\x01", "\x02", etc) and a dictionary to convert from strings to integers (conversion_table =  dict([('\x00', 0x00), ('\x01', 0x01), ('\x02', 0x02), etc).  It's ugly, but it allows me to send the few binary bytes I need to send over the ascii pipe.

Comment: Just use `struct.pack('>H', length)`  to convert integer `length` to 2 bytes.